# how to set up restful_authentication email activation using gmail SMTP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, restful-authentication

I have installed restful_authentcation from technoweenie with activation, and so I see the generated UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base.

However, the instructions don't include how to set it up to work with Google SMTP.

I am **guessing** that environments/development.rb needs to have the SMTP settings, but still not sure given Google (via Google apps) are all TLS.

Anyone set up activation using restful_authentication?

I currently put into environments.rb the following:

```
 ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
     :enable_starttls_auto => true,
     :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
     :port => "587",
     :domain => "mydomain.com",
     :authentication => :plain,
     :user_name => "xxx@mydomain.com",
     :password => "mypassword"

}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, ActionMailer doesn't do TLS out of the box (2.3.2). A couple of months ago I had the same issue and found some code on a Japanese page and integrated that. it appears that code has been wrapped up into a plugin now (with english docs yeah!). That's not exactly what I'm using, but it advertises the same effect.

so add this plugin:
http://github.com/openrain/action_mailer_tls/tree/master

and in environments/development.rb or environements.rb you need something like this:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "yourdomain.com",
  :user_name => "first.last@gmail.com",
  :password => "passwd",
  :authentication => :plain
}
```

I see that :enable_starttls_auto => true is now in the docs, but it wasn't when I started. this at least works for me...

Edit: for some reason that link doesn't work if you follow it, but copy paste in the address bar and it's live...

Answer (score 0):

I've never used SMTP from ruby (I have from python), but that *looks* right.  You have the right domain and port (actually, multiple ports are supported, but that's one of them), and you're using starttls and AUTH PLAIN, which Google does use.

Comment: sight, it's not working:

530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. l31sm1276848rvb.39

Comment: Yeah.  I don't know why your ruby lib isn't doing that for you, though.